# Must angular modules have the same version as angularJS itself

Tags: angularjs

When I have installed angularJS 1.2.16 and some other angular modules also version 1.2.16 and I want to update my angularJS 1.2.16 to 1.2.23 will this work?

If yes why do I get such questions: That the angularJS version is not correct for angular mocks or ui-router?

Or do I not correctly interpret that?

```
C:\test>bower install angular#1.2.23 --save
bower angular#>= 1.0.8          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.23
bower angular#>= 1.0.8        validate 1.2.23 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.8
bower angular#1.2.16            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower angular#1.2.16          validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower angular#1.2.23            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.23
bower angular#1.2.23          validate 1.2.23 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.23

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.2.16 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-mocks#1.2.16
    2) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.2.23 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.10
    3) angular#1.2.23 which resolved to 1.2.23

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json


[?] Answer:
```

**UPDATE**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
    "angular": "1.2.23",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.23"
```

Comment: Please show your bower.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, angular and `ng` modules need to have the same version. It might work if their are not but you have no guarantee and it could be a source of weird bugs.
2. You probably have an entry in your bower.json requesting angular-mocks#1.2.16 which depends on angularjs 1.2.16. Please post your bower.json to confirm

You can update your bower.json:

```
"angular-mocks": "1.2.23",
"angular-scenario": "1.2.23"
```

Comment: 1) But there never existed a 1.2.16 version of angular ui-router ust 0.2.10, how could I then ever use this with angular 1.2.16 ? My bower.json is above!

Comment: ui-router is not an official 'angular' module. It is part of the 'angular ui' project. Therefore their versions can mismatch. The proof of that is ui-router requires a version of angular higher than 1.0.8 and this is resolved by 1.2.23 `angular#>= 1.0.8`.

Comment: So when I have a not official angular module I should have a look the the bower.json of the module and check the dependencies property?

Comment: in my opinion, it is not required unless you are encountering version conflicts.

Comment: OK thanks I have updated now to --latest version for all 1.2.16 packages :-)